# How to use unit tests in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, sugarcrm

What has to be done to enable the unit tests that come with sugarcrm?

I've set up phpunit in general settings and added the xml configuration and custom script as shown in the image. I get "Perhaps an error occurred, verify in Output window." but the output window stays empty.

If I run tests/phpunit.php in webserver the tests are running (data is generated) only until the first mysql problem shows up in sugarlog.

[image: Netbeans project properties]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems only the shebang line in tests/phpunit.php has to be set to the correct environment, then the tests are working!

default is: `#!/usr/bin/env php`

In my environment it now looks like:`#!/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.20/bin/php`